# Как сделать шрифт в QPainter больше

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Делаю генератор мемов и хочу сделать нормальный текст а шрифт получается маленьким
как его сделать большим?

Я добавил spinBoX и собираюсь в нем менять размер.Помогите. Делаю  в Qt Creator c++

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17819698/2553424

Answer (score 1):

Примерный код:

```
void Window::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // Получение текущего шрифта painter'а и установка его размера от виджета
    QFont font = painter->font();
    font.setPointSize(spinbix.value());

    painter->setFont(font);
    
    painter.drawText(....);
    ...
```

Не забудьте после изменения значения spinbox вызывать у виджета `update`